# How to get the quaternionic analytic signal of a image?

Tags: image-processing, fourier-transform, hilbert-transform, analytic-signal, quadrature

The 2D discrete image signal's quaternionic fourier transform can be described as F(u,v), and its 2D analytic signal often be described as:

$$
F_q(u,v) = (1 + \mbox{sgn}(u))(1 + \mbox{sgn}(v)) F(u,v)  
$$

$$
\mbox{sgn}(u) \triangleq
\begin{cases}
1&, u>0\\
0&, u=0\\
-1&, u<0
\end{cases}
$$

$F_q(u,v)$: quaternionic analytic signal, F is the fourier trans of f)

$$
QQF(u,v) = (1 + \mbox{sgn}(u))(1 + \mbox{sgn}(v)) F(u,v) H_b(u,v)
$$

$QQF(u,v)$: quaternionic quadrature filter;

$F(u,v)$: quaternionic fourier transform of image $f(x,y)$

$H_b(u,v)$: a band-pass filter, i.e. log-gabor, cauchy, 2d gaussian derivative filter, .etc

in many papers, after the define of quaternionic analytic signal, the author usually gives a specific quaternionic filter (such as quaternionic gabor filter, or quaternionic log-gabor filter) in image processing to demonstrate the useful of this method. (such as use this quaternionic quadrature filter for a image filtering)

Q:

1. after fourier transform, when will u<0.
2. what is the meaning of this quaternionic analytic signal
3. How to implement the code of quaternion gabor filtering(QGF) with matlab?

*Note*: maybe my understanding of this concept is weak, and welcome to give a specific detailed demonstration.